# TinyMCE capture click button event

Tags: tinymce

is it possible in TinyMCE to know which button was clicked? so I could place specific action on specific event of a specific button.

the buttons here are default control-buttons like bold/italic/select-font not a custom button one.

probably in the init, but I have no idea what to call. I could capture the editor's events but not the button's.

For example, let's say I want a messagebox popped-up everytime bold button is clicked. How to capture the click event of bold button? is creating custom button the only way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can define an own command and call this command (+ the defualt action) on buttonklick. I do not know if you want a generic way for all buttons. But it is easy to do it just for one or two buttons.

**Example:** We want to put an action on the bold button.
First we define an own command in one of our own plugins (in the "init : function(ed, url)" -section):

```
ed.addCommand('my_bold', this.my_bold, this); //calls the function my_bold
```

Then we overwrite the default action with an the command:

```
if (ed.controlManager.get('bold')){
    ed.controlManager.get('bold').settings.cmd='my_bold_action';
};
```

Now, we only need to define the function my bold

```
my_bold: function() {           
    // exectution of regular command
    this.editor.execCommand('Bold');

    // now do whatever you like here
    ...
},
```

Comment: sorry, I don't follow. could you provide me an example? thx :)

Comment: But how to do it in version 4. I can not see there controlManager in editor?

Comment: @ironbone: for tinymce 4 it works somewhat different because the behaviour has changed in many places.

Answer (score 1):

`ed.controlManager` must be called in "onInit" methode :

```
ed.onInit.add(function(editor) {
    .......
    ........

    if (editor.controlManager.get('bold')){
       editor.controlManager.get('bold').settings.cmd='my_bold_action'; 
    };

});
```

Comment: -1 'my_bold_action' is useless without the right context, i suggest you do not copy/paste other answers