# Catch pressing button in plugin for tinyMCE

Tags: plugins, tinymce

I want to catch the event of some button was pressed.
In [TinyMCE capture click button event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9665396/tinymce-capture-click-button-event) was suggested simple solution of how to do it, but for me it does not work. Could you please help. Here is my code in tinymce/plugins/test folder in editor_plugin_src.js and editor_plugin.js files:

```
(function(){
tinymce.create("tinymce.plugins.testPlugin",{
    init:function(ed,url){
        ed.addCommand('my_bold', this.my_bold, this); //calls the function my_bold
        ed.onInit.add(function(editor) {
            if (editor.controlManager.get('bold')){
                editor.controlManager.get('bold').settings.cmd='my_bold_action'; 
            };

        });
    },
    my_bold: function() {           
        // exectution of regular command
        this.editor.execCommand('Bold');

        // now do whatever you like here
        alert('pressed');
    },
    createControl:function(b,a){
        return null
    },
    getInfo:function(){
        return{
            longname:"test plugin",
            author:"test author",
            authorurl:"http://tinymce.moxiecode.com",
            infourl:"http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Plugins/example",
            version:"1.0"
        }
    }
});
tinymce.PluginManager.add("test",tinymce.plugins.TestPlugin)     })();
```

Here I activate plugin test:

```
    $(this).tinymce({
        ...
        autoresize_bottom_margin : 15,
        mode : 'exact',
        elements : clickedId,           
        theme : 'advanced',
        plugins : 'autoresize,test',
        force_br_newlines : true,
```

UPDATE:

```
(function(){
tinymce.PluginManager.requireLangPack("test");
tinymce.create("tinymce.plugins.test",{
    init:function(ed,url){
        ed.addCommand('my_bold', this.my_bold, this);//calls the function my_bold
        ed.onInit.add(function(editor) {
            if (editor.controlManager.get('bold')){
                editor.controlManager.get('bold').settings.cmd='my_bold'; 
            }
        });
    },
    my_bold: function() {           
        // exectution of regular command
        this.editor.execCommand('Bold');

        // now do whatever you like here
        alert('pressed');
    },
    createControl:function(ed,url){
        return null
    },
    getInfo:function(){
        return{
           longname:"test plugin",
           author:"test author",
           authorurl:"http://tinymce.moxiecode.com",
           infourl:"http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Plugins/example",
           version:"1.0"
        }
    }
});
tinymce.PluginManager.add("test",tinymce.plugins.test)    })();
```

Now I have this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you added the bold button to your button config?
Something like:

```
theme_advanced_buttons1: "bold,italic,underline";
```

Update:

```
editor.controlManager.get('bold').settings.cmd='my_bold_action';
```

is erroneous, you need:

```
editor.controlManager.get('bold').settings.cmd='my_bold';
```

here.

Comment: yes, like this:  theme_advanced_buttons1:'bold,sup,sub,underline,bullist,undo',

Comment: I have edited as you wrote. Now it is much better, but still does not work :)  Console error _this.editor is undefined_ in _this.editor.execCommand('Bold');_. Please look at my update.

Comment: It works, but with tinyMCE.activeEditor.execCommand('Bold'); Thank you!