# TinyMCE add another event to bold and italic buttons?

Tags: javascript, tinymce

Do you know how to add another custom event to fire when the bold and italic button are pressed. After each button is pressed I would like to get the updated html text by calling the function  `boldItalicPressed()`

```
   tinyMCE.init({
      mode : "textareas",
      theme : "advanced",
      theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,
      onchange_callback : "myCustomOnChangeHandler"

   });

   function myCustomOnChangeHandler(inst) {
        alert("Some one modified something");
        alert("The HTML is now:" + inst.getBody().innerHTML);
   }

   function boldItalicPressed(){
        alert(tinyMCE.get('mytextarea').getContent());
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11473576/catch-pressing-button-in-plugin-for-tinymce) might be of help to you.
Problem here is that there is no catchable event fired when the bold button is pressed.
The solution is to register a custom tinymce command and to replace the command executed on bold-button-click with that one.
The new command will execute the regular bold command plus the other stuff you want to execute then.