# How can I change the styles of content if contentedittable = false?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

Hey I have created a plugin that opens a new dialog (an extra HTML-page).
With this dialog the user have the opportunity to create his own format pattern.

What would I like to have?
I need a tinymce editor with a readonly textarea (no problem). But the user must be able to select formats like bold, italic, underline, fontsize, fontfamily, ...

There is a sample text in the textarea which displays the formatting.
And here is the problem.
I can set the formats if the textarea is readonly.

Anyone have an idea?

I use jquery-ui to create the dialog.
Here is the javascript block :

```
<script>
    //Wandelt die Auswahlbutton(Formatvorlage & Tastenkombination) in Selectmenüs um
    $(function () {
        $('#selFormatvorlagen').selectmenu();
        $('#selTastenkombination').selectmenu();

    });

    //Button Neu
    $(function () {
        $("#NewFormatDialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 150,
            width: 400,
            resizable: false,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "OK": function () {
                    var content = $('#NameFormatpattern').val();
                    //Einfügen eines neuen Elements
                    $("<option value='" + content + "'>" + content + "</option>").appendTo("#selFormatvorlagen");
                    $("#selFormatvorlagen").selectmenu("refresh");
                    $('#NameFormatpattern').val('');
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                },
                "Abbrechen": function () {
                    $('#NameFormatpattern').val('');
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            },
            close: function () {
                $('#NameFormatpattern').val('');
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        });

        //Button Umbenennen
        $("#ChangeFormatNameDialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 150,
            width: 400,
            resizable: false,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "OK": function () {
                    var content = $("#ChangeFormatName").val();
                    var selectedName = $("#selFormatvorlagen option:selected").text();
                    $('select option:contains("' + selectedName + '")').text(content);
                    $("#selFormatvorlagen").selectmenu("refresh");
                    $('#ChangeFormatName').val('');
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                },
                "Abbrechen": function () {
                    $('#ChangeFormatName').val('');
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            },
            close: function () {
                $('#ChangeFormatName').val('');
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        });

        //Button Löschen
        $("#DeleteFormatDialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 150,
            width: 400,
            resizable: false,
            modal: true,
            closeText: "Close",
            buttons: {
                "Ja": function () {
                    $('#selFormatvorlagen').find('option:selected').remove();
                    $("#selFormatvorlagen").selectmenu("refresh");
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                },
                "Nein": function () {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                },
            },
            close: function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        });

        //Öffnen der Dialoge bzw. Zuweisung der Buttons
        $("#btnNeu").button().on("click", function () {
            $("#NewFormatDialog").dialog("open");
        });
        $("#btnUmbenennen").button().on("click", function () {
            $("#ChangeFormatNameDialog").dialog("open");
        });
        $("#btnLöschen").button().on("click", function () {
            $("#DeleteFormatDialog").dialog("open");
        });
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Initialisierung des Editors
    function init() {
        tinymce.init({
            language: "de",
            selector: 'textarea#txtFormatvorlage',
            fontsize_formats: "8pt 9pt 10pt 11pt 12pt 14pt 16pt 18pt 20pt 22pt 24pt 26pt 28pt 36pt 48pt 72pt",
            font_formats: getFontFamily(),
            plugins: "textcolor paste code",
            menubar: false,
            toolbar: "removeformat | fontselect | fontsizeselect |  bold italic underline strikethrough | alignleft aligncenter alignright | forecolor",
            contextmenu: false,
            setup: function (editor) {
                //Textarea wird bei der Initialisierung auf readonly gesetzt
                editor.on('Init', function (ed) {
                    editor.execCommand('SelectAll');
                    editor.getBody().setAttribute('contenteditable', 'false');
                });
            }
        });
    }

    //Der Editor wird neu initialisiert
    function reinitialize() {
        try {
            remove("txtFormatvorlage");
            init();
        }
        catch (err) {
            init();
        }
    }

    //Erste Initialisierung
    init();

</script>
```

And here is the dialog html-page:

```
<body>
<div id="container">
        <div>
            <form id="MenuTop">
                <span class="selectMenuIndicator">Formatvorlage:</span> 
                <select id="selFormatvorlagen">
                    <option value="Black">Black</option>
                    <option value="my own formatpattern">my own formatpattern</option>
                </select>
                <input class="MenuButton" id="btnNeu" type= "Button" value="Neu">
                <input class="MenuButton" id="btnUmbenennen" type= "Button" value="Umbenennen">
                <input class="MenuButton" id="btnLöschen" type="Button" value="Löschen"> 
            </form>
            <form id="MenuBottom">
                <span class="selectMenuIndicator">Tastenkombination ( Alt + ):</span> 
                <select name="selTastenkombination" id="selTastenkombination">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                    <option value="7">7</option>
                    <option value="8">8</option>
                    <option value="9">9</option>
                    <option value="0">0</option>
                </select>
            </form>
        </div>         
</div>

<textarea id="txtFormatvorlage" rows="5" style="box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%; height: 100%">sample text</textarea>

<!--Eingabe des Formatvorlagennamens-->
<div id="NewFormatDialog" title="Neue Formatvorlage anlegen">
    <form>
        <fieldset>
            <label for="NameFormatpattern">Bitte geben Sie den Namen der neuen Formatvorlage ein.</label>
            <input type="text" name="NameFormatpattern" id="NameFormatpattern" class="inputTextDialog">
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>

<!--Eingabe des Formatvorlagennamens-->
<div id="ChangeFormatNameDialog" title="Formatvorlage umbenennen">
    <form>
        <fieldset>
            <label for="ChangeFormatName">Bitte geben Sie den neuen Namen für die Formatvorlage ein.</label>
            <input type="text" name="ChangeFormatName" id="ChangeFormatName" class="inputTextDialog">
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>

<!--Eingabe des Formatvorlagennamens-->
<div id="DeleteFormatDialog" title="KORAKTOR">
    <label>Wollen sie die Formatvorlage wirklich löschen?</label>
</div>
```

Sorry I have not enought reputation to post pictures and it is hard to explane. :/
I hope anyone have a solution for me. :)
Thanks Felix

**EDIT:** Yeah I have founded a solution:
There are two commands "BeforeExecCommand" and "ExecCommand"
http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:event.tinymce.Editor.BeforeExecCommand
http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:event.tinymce.Editor.ExecCommand

And here is the code:

```
editor.on('Init', function (ed) {
    editor.getBody().setAttribute('contenteditable', 'false');                  
});

editor.on('BeforeExecCommand', function () {
    editor.getBody().setAttribute('contenteditable', 'true');
});

editor.on('ExecCommand', function () {
    editor.getBody().setAttribute('contenteditable', 'false');
});
```

But now I have an other problem. Before I can change the fontstyle I have to select all. But this command doesn`t work:

```
editor.execCommand('selectAll');

editor.on('BeforeExecCommand', function () {
    editor.getBody().setAttribute('contenteditable', 'true');
    editor.execCommand('selectAll');
});
```

How can I select all to change the fontstyle?

**Edit2:** The command "selectAll" selected wrong. This code is the solution:

```
editor.on('BeforeExecCommand', function (e) {
    if (e.command != 'selectAll') {
        //Select the rigth node
        node = editor.dom.select('p')[0];
        while (node.children.length > 0) {
        node = node.children[0];
        }
        editor.selection.select(node);

        editor.getBody().setAttribute('contenteditable', 'true');
    }
 });

 editor.on('ExecCommand', function (e) {
     if (e.command != 'selectAll') {
         editor.selection.collapse();
         editor.getBody().setAttribute('contenteditable', 'false');
      }
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When making a style change, turn off readonly, apply the style, and turn it back on. It will take milliseconds.

Comment: Thanks but how can I catch the event from the, for example, bold button, to turn off the readonly?

Comment: Ahhh I found something: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9665396/tinymce-capture-click-button-event
I report you if it works :)

Comment: http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/3_x/setup_editor_events.php, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15599251/tinymce-adding-event-listeners-issue

Comment: Ok I have tested the solution, but it doesn't work. The event in your first post works only for the mouse click event. And in the second link, the keyPress event, doesn't work too. I need a Button click event. Is there something?
The solution in my comment doesn't work with the tinymce version 4. :(
Is there any onther solution? thx