# Tinymce: How do I get the formatting of my selected node?

Tags: javascript, css, tinymce-4

Hi guys is there any possibility to get all formats of my node?
I need a solution to read and set the formats.

I have this example:

```
alert(node.style.color)
```

But I haven't found any more styles. Is there any other styles too or an other solution to get the styles?

(I need this function for my format edit project. More information here: [How can I change the styles of content if contentedittable = false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25447463/how-can-i-change-the-styles-of-content-if-contentedittable-false))

thanks Felix

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your selection spans. The selection has two sections: startContainer and endContainer, each of them representing a different node structure.
To get the starting node of your selection you can do:

`var startNode = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getWin().window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).startContainer`

and for the end container you can do:

`var endNode = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getWin().window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).endContainer`

If the node is not a text node, then you can get the styling, otherwise you have to get the parent node.

Comment: I have for example this in my textarea, which is replaced with the tinymce editor.
        <p><em><strong>sample text</strong></em></p>
And my node is "<p>" and now I need all styles. In this example strong and italic

Comment: In that scenario you can simply use: tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent(), this will return you the body of the editor as a normal HTML node, from there you can do anything you want.

Comment: But I need the node formats in this format:
{title: 'Red text', inline: 'span', styles: {color: '#ff0000'}}
I found this: tinymce.activeEditor.dom.getStyle(node, "font-size", true)

Comment: With this code line you can check all formats. Only the alignment doesn't work.

Comment: Right I see what you're after. The alignment is called 'justifyleft', 'justifyright' etc. To get the custom formatting of the nodes you'll need some custom JS to get what you're after

Comment: I have an other way. At first I select the first p-tag and then I can use the command:

Comment: node = editor.dom.select('p')[0];                            alert(tinymce.activeEditor.dom.getStyle(node, "text-align", true)) because the alignment is stored in the first p-tag

Comment: Yes you can only get the styles applied to the current node. The other way, but longer would be to the the computed styles, which would give you all the inherited properties.

Comment: Mhh ok but nevermind it works xD
Nevertheless thanks for your attention. :)